# How much design work did JARVIS do for the Iron Man suits

Tags: marvel, iron-man

In the movies, it’s implied that Tony did all the design work for the various suits, but is that really the case? For things like the suitcase suit, [that’s something an AI could solve faster than a person](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/ames/research/exploringtheuniverse/borg.html), plus Jarvis had more access to all of the Stark design databases, and could apply those to the suits. Is there any mention in the comics or novelizations(if there are any) of how much JARVIS actually contributed to the design?

Comment: “Jarvis had more access to all of the Stark design databases” — more access than Tony?

Comment: @PaulD.Waite yeah, Tony has to sleep and eat, and can really only work on one thing at a time, whereas Jarvis could probably look up multiple things at once.

Comment: `that’s something an AI could solve faster than a person` - [citation needed]

Comment: @KevinWorkman Two years prior to the movie's release, NASA had a program that designed antennae using evolutionary algorithms, included a reference to that.

Comment: Are you asking solely about the MCU or Marvel as a whole? I took the question to be about the MCU with comics referring to the supplementary comics but at present it is a bit unclear what you're referring to.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Any resource, that's why I only included the Marvel tag and not MCU.

Comment: If Tony sets multiple algorithms going for JARVIS to perform like when creating Ultron, did Tony do the work or JARVIS?

Comment: @CBredlow I think designing a suitcase suit is much more complex than designing a single component, and having a human in the loop is probably required even for Jarvis, but kudos for finding a reference.